# XSL conflict while parsing BBCode

Tags: java, xsl-fo

i'm trying to write code that parse the BBCODE in Xsl file, the input is `[b]text[/b]` for

example, and the output should the word text but in bold, i've done java class with method

called `parseBBCode` and import it in the xsl file, this method parses the BBCode and make a

new xsl tag with the new font style for example:

```
<fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="font.arial.8" font-style="bold"> text</fo:inline>
```

the problem occurs when calling the method from the xsl file and passes to it the Xpath of the

text it prints

the Actual : the return value of the method as a normal text not as a xsl tags means it prints

the text as

```
<fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="font.arial.8" font-style="bold"> text</fo:inline>
```

The Expected: i need them to deal with the output as tags to print the right value.

Comment: I don't understand. You'll have to explain this better. Do you have actual BBCode markup in an XSL file? How can anyone reproduce the problem?

Comment: yes, i've actual BBCode in XSL and i want to parse them in the xsl to appear with the format of BBCode, and my solution was
1- i've made a new java class (and included it in the xsl file as anamespace) to parse the String that have the bbcode and return the XSL tags like 
<fo:inline font-weight="bold">0172-220577</fo:inline>
the problem appears when calling the java method in the xsl it returns the output as a string and the final output of the xsl contains the <fo:inline> tag and it's attributes which shouldn't appear, "it should parsed as XSL Tags"

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is still very hard to understand. Again: how can the problem be reproduced? Please **update the question** instead of adding comments. Please consider providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: hello mzjn can we contact on private mail to be able to understand each other ?

Comment: any one can help me in this problem please?

Comment: You haven't made it easy for other people to help you. The current revision (6) of the question does not contain all relevant information. I think that the main problem is that your XSLT extension method `parseBBCode` (whose source is in [revision 5](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10618267/5) of this question) returns a string instead of a DOM `Document`.